# minimum value within two worksheet in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I find the minimum values among two worksheets for a particular column

suppose,

`worksheet 1`

```
index    A   B   C
   0     2   3   4.28
   1     3   4   5.23
```

`worksheet 2`

```
index    A   B   C
    0    9   6   5.9
    1    1   3   4.1
```

by comparing C column, I want an answer, where dataframe looks like

```
index      min(c)
    0       4.28
    1       4.1
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the minimum C value for each worksheet, or for each index, across worksheets?

Comment: df = pd.concat([d1,d2])
df = df.groupby(df.index).min()

Comment: I want to find the minimum value for each index across all worksheet, you can see the above example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`np.fmin`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.fmin.html) to find the min

```
np.fmin(ws1.C, ws2.C)

index
0    4.28
1    4.10
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

---

**Setup**
For others to try

```
ws1 = pd.DataFrame([
        [2, 3, 4.28],
        [3, 4, 5.23]
    ], pd.Index([0, 1], name='index'), list('ABC'))

ws2 = pd.DataFrame([
        [9, 6, 5.9],
        [1, 3, 4.1]
    ], pd.Index([0, 1], name='index'), list('ABC'))
```

Comment: I got the different output by`np.fmin`, `0    4.10
1    5.23`

Comment: I'd have to see exactly what you're running.

Comment: `np.fmin(df1.c, df2.c)` ,`df1` and `df2` are `DataFrame`

Comment: And also what your dataframes are.  Try my dataframes that I defined in the post.

Comment: It is worked! thank you ~also , I will open a question about this hope you can help me out

Comment: just out of curiosity, what if there are more than two worksheets?

Comment: `from functools import reduce` then `reduce(np.fmin, [ws1.C, ws2.C, ws3.C])`